# Multiple HTTP Requests /w Single Socket

Tags: java, http, sockets

I am creating an HTTP client, which handles HTTP requests and responses with a socket. It is able to send the first request and read the response stream. However the subsequent requests do not write anything to the input stream.

```
static String host/* = some host*/;
static int port/* = some port*/;

private Socket sock = null;
private BufferedWriter outputStream = null;
private BufferedReader inputStream = null;

public HttpClient() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

    sock = new Socket(host, port);
    outputStream = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream()));
    inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
    sock.setKeepAlive(true);
    sock.setTcpNoDelay(true);
}

/* ... */
public String sendGetRequest(String relAddr) throws IOException {

    outputStream.write("GET " + relAddr + " HTTP/1.0\r\n");
    outputStream.write("\r\n");
    outputStream.flush();

    String line;
    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();

    while((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
        buff.append(line);
        buff.append("\n");
    }

    return buff.toString();
}
```

In the main method, I use the following:

```
client = new HttpClient();
str = client.sendGetRequest(addr);
System.out.println(str);
/* and again */
str = client.sendGetRequest(addr);
System.out.println(str);
```

But only the first sendGetRequest invoke returns a response string. The subsequent ones do not. Do you have an idea?

Comment: You should probably `open()` and `close()` the Input/Output Streams for every request you make... even though the socket is reused.

Comment: Actually if I recreate the client object before each request, everything works perfectly. However I want that socket to be persistent.

Comment: @Marcelo No. That would close the socket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP 1.0 does not support persistent connections as part of the actual specification (apparently there is an [unofficial extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection)).  You need to switch to 1.1 (or use the unofficial extension, assuming the server supports it).

Comment: @EdwardThomson - added clarification, and TIL about keep alives under HTTP 1.0.

Comment: That's fair.  I admit it's not in the spec for HTTP/1.0, though worth pointing out that even ancient versions of Apache and IIS support keep-alive with HTTP/1.0.

Comment: Upvoted unexplained downvote. Answer is correct; unexplained downvotes are frequently incorrect, as here.